# Cumulative Sum using 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-frequency

I am trying to create a column that does a cumulative sum using 2 columns , please see example of what I am trying to do :@Faith Akici

```
  index lodgement_year  words       sum  cum_sum
    0   2000            the          14     14
    1   2000            australia    10     10
    2   2000            word         12     12
    3   2000            brand         8      8
    4   2000            fresh         5      5
    5   2001            the           8      22
    6   2001            australia     3      13
    7   2001            banana        1       1
    8   2001            brand         7      15
    9   2001            fresh         1       6
```

I have used the code below , however my computer keep crashing , I am unsure if is the code or the computer. Any help will be greatly appreciated:

```
   df_2['cumsum']= df_2.groupby('lodgement_year')['words'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
```

Update ; I have also used the code below , it worked and said exit code 0 . However with some warnings.

```
df_2['cum_sum'] =df_2.groupby(['words'])['count'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Is it `'lodgement_year'` or `'lodgement_date'`?

Comment: Hi its lodgemement_year (sorry) . @Piinthesky I just though that I would reference the previous problem for context. But yes happy to delete.

Comment: Is 'lodgement_year' needed? Based on the sample output, it seems that cumulative sum is just based on 'words'?

Comment: Can you show the expected output dataframe?

Comment: Hi, sorry ... the cum_sum above is the column I was trying to create. and the code below worked , however it printed some warnings at the top.

      df_2['cum_sum'] =df_2.groupby(['words'])['count'].cumsum()

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira You almost got it, but there is a simple mistake in your code. Please see my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, Ian!

`cumsum()` method calculates the cumulative sum of a Pandas column. You are looking for that applied to the grouped `words`. Therefore:

```
In [303]: df_2['cumsum'] = df_2.groupby(['words'])['sum'].cumsum()

In [304]: df_2
Out[304]: 
   index  lodgement_year      words  sum  cum_sum  cumsum
0      0            2000        the   14       14      14
1      1            2000  australia   10       10      10
2      2            2000       word   12       12      12
3      3            2000      brand    8        8       8
4      4            2000      fresh    5        5       5
5      5            2001        the    8       22      22
6      6            2001  australia    3       13      13
7      7            2001     banana    1        1       1
8      8            2001      brand    7       15      15
9      9            2001      fresh    1        6       6
```

Please comment if this fails on your bigger data set, and we'll work on a possibly more accurate version of this.

Comment: As usual , thanks Fatih for your support. It worked and the code I was using :  df_2['cum_sum'] =df_2.groupby(['words'])['count'].cumsum() also worked. I will make sure I spell your name right in the next question:)

Comment: @ FatihAkici , like this? Next discussion , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175666/deploying-a-pandas-data-frame-to-a-url-using-urllib-and-getting-the-results-in-a

Answer (score 0):

If we only need to consider the column 'words', we might need to loop through unique values of the words

```
for unique_words in df_2.words.unique():
    if 'cum_sum' not in df_2:
        df_2['cum_sum'] = df_2.loc[df_2['words'] == unique_words]['sum'].cumsum()
    else:
        df_2.update(pd.DataFrame({'cum_sum': df_2.loc[df_2['words'] == unique_words]['sum'].cumsum()}))
```

above will result to:

```
>>> print(df_2)
  lodgement_year  sum      words  cum_sum
0           2000   14        the     14.0
1           2000   10  australia     10.0
2           2000   12       word     12.0
3           2000    8      brand      8.0
4           2000    5      fresh      5.0
5           2001    8        the     22.0
6           2001    3  australia     13.0
7           2001    1     banana      1.0
8           2001    7      brand     15.0
9           2001    1      fresh      6.0
```

Comment: Hi strangely your code do not run on my file. My file contains 120 years of data and around 650k words per year, could that be a issue? Would you be able to try my code and give me some feedback? Thanks