# Loop every row from a pandas data frame to a url using urllib and return XML results in a same file

Tags: python, pandas, loops, url

Im trying to deploy a pandas data frame to a URL and get the return from some fields in new columns in the same data frame.The aim is to loop through each row.

The data frame looks like this :

```
name       state    postcode    VIC NSW ACT NT
coles       VIC      2501        Y  N   N   N
woolworth   NSW      3409        N  Y   N   N
big w       ACT      3201        N  N   Y   N
target      NT       1089        N  N   N   Y
```

I want the name of my columns per row to be deployed and the results in new columns as the example show below. The code below works but I can only make work manually.

```
import urllib.request as req

name = ''
postcode = ''
legalName = ''      
tradingName = ''    
NSW = ''            
SA = ''             
ACT = ''            
VIC = ''            
WA = ''             
NT = ''             
QLD = ''            
TAS = ''            
authenticationGuid = 'b6aaddd4-8463-4d76-9e24-99530f5df326'     #Your GUID should go here

#Constructs the URL by inserting the search parameters specified above
#GETs the url (using urllib.request.urlopen)
conn = req.urlopen('http://abr.business.gov.au/abrxmlsearchRPC/AbrXmlSearch.asmx/' + 
                'ABRSearchByNameSimpleProtocol?name=' + name + 
                '&postcode=' + postcode + '&legalName=' + legalName + 
                '&tradingName=' + tradingName + '&NSW=' + NSW + 
                '&SA=' + SA + '&ACT=' + ACT + '&VIC=' +  VIC + 
                '&WA=' + WA + '&NT=' + NT + '&QLD=' + QLD + 
                '&TAS=' + TAS + '&authenticationGuid=' + authenticationGuid)

#XML is returned by the webservice
#Put returned xml into variable 'returnedXML' 
#Output xml string to file 'output.xml' and print to console
returnedXML = conn.read()
f = open('output.xml', 'wb')
f.write(returnedXML)
f.close
print(returnedXML)
```

Comment: So what is `ABN`? A field in the `returnedXML`? And why is it the same across all rows?

Comment: ABN is australian business number , if you deploy the URL code and just use a name for example coles it will return all the info including ABN plus many more variables . This variables I would like to become columns in pandas format.